# Is it allowed for 3 sisters to 3 brothers marry at same time?

Tags: nikah, sunnah

Is it permissible for a family to marry their 3 daughters to another family's 3 brothers at same time?

Answer (score 3):

In Islam, the default is what is not explicitly forbidden is allowed.

I am scratching my head on this one. Reviewing all conditions for a marriage, I don't see why a "group" marriage would violate any of the rules of marriage.

So yes, absolutely.